# Get user's "Your Music" on Spotify

Tags: ios, spotify, libspotify, cocoalibspotify-2.0

Is it possible to get `"Your Music"` which contains `playlists, songs, and albums` from Spotify using `Cocoalibspotify`?

Right now I am only able to get playlists from "Your Music" using:

```
[SPSession sharedSession].userPlaylists.flattenedPlaylists.
```

Answer (score 0):

No - Your Music is a very new feature, and CocoaLibSpotify's last release was quite a long time ago.

Comment: I see. However, if I get [SPSession sharedSession].userPlaylists.flattenedPlaylists some items causes a [NSNULL isLoaded] error and crashes my app.